# Сравнение и замена текста в 2 txt файлах

Tags: c++

Помогите, пожалуйста, кодом решения следующей проблемы:

есть два txt файла — первый содержит текст следующего вида:

> Андрей;123;789 Светлана;7250;924 Игорь;756758;7538

второй содержит текст следующего вида:

> 123;789;QQQ 7250;924;RRR 756758;7538;TTT

Нужно сделать их сравнение и замену при совпадении и сохранение в отдельный файл. Пример:

```
Андрей;123;789 = 123;789;QQQ сохранение Андрей;QQQ
```

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream ifs1{"file1.txt"};
    std::ifstream ifs2{"file2.txt"};
    if (ifs1.is_open() && ifs2.is_open())
    {
        std::ofstream ofs{"results.txt"};
        std::transform(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(ifs1), {},
                       std::istream_iterator<std::string>(ifs2),
                       std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(ofs, "\n"),
                       [](std::string s1, std::string s2) {
                           static const std::string f = "BBB;CCC";
                           auto it1 = s1.find(f);
                           auto it2 = s2.find(f);
                           if (it1 != std::string::npos && it2 != std::string::npos) {
                               s1.erase(it1, f.size());
                               s2.erase(it2, f.size());
                               if (s1.rfind(';') == s1.size()-1)
                                   s1.erase(s1.size()-1);
                               if (s2.rfind(';') == s2.size()-1)
                                   s2.erase(s2.size()-1);
                               return s1 + s2;
                           }
                       }
        );
    }
    else
        std::cerr << "Error opening files!\n";
}
```

Comment: Предоставьте пожалуйста пример Вашего кода.и те моменты в коде которые Вам не понятны.

Comment: добавил код в 1 пост мне нужно сделать значение BBB;CCC которое берётся из второго файла не постоянным т.е в каждой строке оно может быть разным

Comment: так а что не получается? что в отладчике?

Comment: код работает но мне нужно сделать значение BBB;CCC не постоянным